# Store Array Locations in Variable

Tags: python, arrays

I'm building a simple game, using Python, with a 2D array as a board. I user can enter numbers to play, but those numbers do not correlate very well to a place on the board.

Can I store a location of an array in a variable so that I do not have to write out board[x][y] every time I check a conditional?

So instead of:

```
if num == 1:
    if board[3][5] == "Z":
        print "Not empty!"
    else 
        board[3][5] = "Z"
```

I can use:

```
if num == 1:
    if locationOf1 == "Z":
        print "Not Empty!"
    else
        locationOf1 == "Z"
```

All I want locationOf1 to do is refer me to where board[3][5] is. How can this be done?

[edited] Or even better (is this possible?):

```
locations = *[location of board[5][1],location of board[5][3]]*

if locations[num] == "Z":
        print "Not empty!"
    else
        locations[num]  == "Z"
```

Comment: You should probably just write a method that takes in a number from the player and translates it to the correct board position. Your method can return the correct position on the board.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, that's what I'm already doing -- it's just not clean. I have 10 if statements I'd like to make the code cleaner. Ideally I could storage array locations in an array so that locations[num] actually refers to a location in the board[][].

Comment: Seems to me that `locations[n]` would take _more_ effort to write than `board[x][y]`. The former is one character longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to store informations based on keys is the dict. You could save the values as a tuple:

```
locations = {1: (3, 5), 2: (4,3)}

def get_location(num):
    x, y = locations.get(num, (-1, -1, ))
    if coords != (-1,-1): 
       return board[x,y]
    else:
       return None
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to create a wrapper class for your 2D array. The encapsulation would give meaning to your game board and easier to work with.

eg.

```
Class BoardWrapper {
   private int[][] board;

   public BoardWrapper(int w, int l) {
      board = new int[w][l];
   }

   public locationOf1() {
      if (board[3][5] == "Z") {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like `Python` to me :) (See tags)

Comment: lol how did I end up here. I'm writing Java at the moment, so I made the leap. my mistake. but strategy still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you already have an array at your disposal, you can not do a faster look-up as you already have a constant look-up time. I would use a map with key as std::string and values as int* (c++) to map strings of the form "locationof1" to an integer pointer pointing to the actual address in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to map board coords to a single value, I guess that have some meaning for the game since x,y coords sound simple enough.

I'd statically map those coords to model the board with a dict, and another dict to the current board state:

```
from collections import defaultdict

board = {
    1: (1, 2),
    3: (3, 4)
}

board_state = defaultdict(str)
```

Then just use locations[x] to get or set the state ("Z").

**UPDATE**:

```
def set_value(val, pos):
    assert pos in board
    board_state[pos] = val

def get_value(pos):
    assert pos in board
    return board_state[pos]
```

Just to illustrate a use case, you can of course just use the board_state. The assert here is optional and depends on your code, you can validate that elsewhere (user input, etc...)